# CSS3 targeting issue

Tags: html, css

first question here so please go easy on me :).

I started studying css3 two weeks ago, and now i'm trying to build a pure css3 dropdown menu system.
I got my menu built like this

```
<body> 
        <div id="column">
            <div id="header">
                <heading1>Header.</heading1>
            </div>

            <div id="menu">
                <a href="Home.html"><menu-element class="chosen"> Home page</menu-element></a>
                <a href="Project.html"><menu-element>Project</menu-element></a>
                <a href="Gallery.html">
                    <menu-element> Gallery
                        <ul>
                            <li>1</li>
                            <li>2</li>
                        </ul>
                    </menu-element>
                </a>

            </div>
....
</body>
```

I'm working by integrating the css code i studied on a tutorial to work on my css structure. 
The step i'm having problem is is the first: hiding the submenu items when not on mouseover.

I tried with

```
menu-element ul
{
    display: none;
}
```

to hide only **ul** elements nested in **menu-element** elements, but it didn't work.. and the **ul** and its **li** childs are still there. Could anyone help me out by telling me where i'm wrong?

Comment: What are `heading1` and `menu-element`? These aren't valid HTML elements, so I suspect CSS doesn't understand these either.

Comment: Just use the basic `nav/ul/li/a` structure like everyone else...please! Here's one I keep around for reference: http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/22c4ca602bda363099133ded6bca2294

Comment: People, as I commented below I know I'm using an unorthodox element structure naming, but I don't get why that should limit css effects on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are doing your tests in IE, and in some of the old compatibility modes.

In Chrome, Firefox, and IE 11, your code works

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DCLe9/)

code fragment to make SO happy:

```
menu-element ul
{
    display: none;
}
```

[image: Chrome dev tools]

It is true that your elements are not valid HTML types, (and of course you should use valid ones!!) but HTML5 compliant browser are quite liberal about that.

Answer (score 1):

Your only problem is that you have invalid html tags, (`<menu-element>` and `<heading1>`).

Instead of `<menu-element>` use `<nav>`, and instead of `<heading1>` use `<h1>`.

Comment: When did `<menu>` become an element...? Did you mean `<nav>`?

Comment: @Paulie_D <nav> is by far the better choice, but <menu> is a valid html tag.

Comment: The <menu> element was deprecated in HTML 4.01.

Comment: Yea, I just saw that. Editing post

Comment: @Paulie_D: It was reintroduced ("undeprecated"?) in HTML5, according to your link.

Comment: I'm confused, is `<menu>` deprecated or not?

Comment: I know i didn't use orthodox elements, but why sould that affect CSS effectiveness on them? I'm using tags in (I think) correct way, so why should "menu-element" give me problems and "nav" not? Thanks for your patience guys!

Comment: @boltClock @ Jaxon On further investigation the `<menu>` element was re-introduced but not for the context in which it is being used here. Interesting.

Comment: @user3347975 Creating you own elements means that the browser may not recognise them, in which case, it cannot parse the CSS to apply it.

Comment: Mmmh... I still don't get why, but your answer was super helpful, since I didn't really think there was a difference between using standard elements and creating my own. May i hit you up in private, @Paulie_D ?  I got some more questions to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice in creating navigation menus is to use an unordered list for the entire menu. This way if styles are not loaded (for whatever reason) it still reads properly. As other have mentioned,  and  are not valid tags.

I would suggest using the model below:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="Project.html">Project</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="Gallery.html">Gallery</a>
            <ul class="gallery">
                <li>1</li>
                <li>2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
     </ul>
</nav>
```

And for the css you could use

```
ul.gallery{
    display: none;
}
```

or

```
nav ul li ul{
    display: none;
}
```

I use the second option when creating pure css dropdown menus as it is easier to follow along as you create more complicated menus. It also allows you to hide all submenus rather than just the one with the class of gallery.